# Alternatives to decompiling MS Access MDE files

Tags: ms-access, reverse-engineering

I've been tasked with finding a suitable tool to decompile MDE files. The MDEs were created by staff who have since left (familar story eh?) and we do not have access to the originally MDB files.

The reason we need access to the original code is that the data source is changing (the backend as well as some of the table and queries) and we need a way to update queries. An example of a change, in a SELECT statement where is the WHERE clause looks for zero as a string ("0") rather than an integer.

I'm aware that unless you use the services of people like EverythingAccess.com its unlikely you will ever get the source code back.

My main query is to ask for alternative methods to decompiling code. An example of the kinds of methods I'm thinking about is to spy on the traffic between the app the the ODBC DSN using tcpdump. I might then be able to write code to translate the data source queries between the old and new systems.

Ideally I'd prefer a solution that is application centric rather than one that analyses all network traffic.

I should add one caveat, no doubt most of you are thinking the best solution is to rewrite the code, based on its perceived functionality. This is the option we're not considering (at the moment).

Comment: Have you tried locating the original MDBs? There is simply no good way to decompile an MDE. My bet is that any tool that purports to do it is going to leave you with almost as much work as it would take to recreate the app from scratch. That latter is really not as complicated as you might think for Access, since most of your standard Access app is not going to be code-centric.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Queries and linked tables can be changed in an MDE.

Alternatively see <strike>Converting a Microsoft Access MDE file back into an MDB file</strike>.  Section 2 for some tips

I see you're already aware of [MDE to MDB Conversion Service for Microsoft Access](http://www.everythingaccess.com/mdeconversion.htmv)   Wayne has stated he will require proof that you own the code.